# kibana's timelion not showing data when data range is less than 150 minutes

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have an SLK stack on windows 10, running kibana 4.5.1, Elasticsearch 2.3.3 and logstash 2.3.2 and timelion (i cant find the version).

I have been experiencing some odd behavior. 
I am collecting "stats" on a date field from solr, when viewing this data in timelion and the date range is less than or equal to 150 minutes then no data is displayed. When using kibana vanilla this data is present for all sizes of date range and the data was displayed fine. If I use data from a different logstash instance then it works fine. The 2 logstash instances are identical other than the urls being polled and they have both been restarted to see if that effected anything.

Can anyone give me a reason why looking at data from this one instance's data to not display if using a data range of less than 150 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why its doing this, the buckets were smaller than 1/2 the interval of collecting the data therefore there were 2 adjacent buckets without any data. I am unsure as to why this breaks things but oh well.